# ckeditor - Clicking on the browse server button to open a javascript dialog rather than popup?

Tags: file-upload, ckeditor

What I want to do is that when the user choose a template in the ckeditor,
they can browse the images which are previously uploaded in the server.

I follow the offical development guide 
http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_(Uploader)#Basic_Configuration

In which it said

> The sample below shows basic configuration code that can be used to insert a CKEditor instance with the file browser configured.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
{
    filebrowserBrowseUrl : '/browser/browse.php',
    filebrowserUploadUrl : '/uploader/upload.php'
});
```

where '/browser/browse.php' is the external file uploader.

However in my system there is a fileuploader which is generated by a javascript.

I would like to call the javascript function to open a file upload dialog, rather than open a new popup when the 'browse server' button is clicked.

Anyone know what should I do?

Thanks